# How can we configure a Datasource as for Camunda DMN

Tags: rule-engine, bpmn, business-rules, camunda

I am using Camunda DMN for managing rules in my application.
I want the input/output conditions of the rules to be updated by the end users, is there a way to connect to it to Database and have the values fetched directly from there?

Note: I have already looked into the redeploy process by updating the DMN file.

Please suggest what can be done and which one would be better?

Comment: I need something similar, so did you found any strategy in order to provide data to the decision from database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The by far simpliest approach is to just edit the dmn files. Not sure on datasource connection, but if you need dynamic, you can either generate the dmn based on your datasource or use groovy expression language and call services/daos during evaluation to get data from external sources.

Answer (score 0):

Your constraints:

> rules to be updated by the end users
>   a way to connect to it to Database

One option:

Create an java/rest/other external service say MyABCDecissionService. That service can call a rules table in a database, and return the decission to Camunda workflow. Users can be given another interface to update the rules in db

This OpenRules api may help. https://openrules.com/external_rules_from_db.htm

[image]